# TensorFlow Operator Source Code

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to find the source code for TensorFlow's low level linear-algebra and matrix arithmetic operators for execution on CPU. For example, where is the actual implementation of `tf.add()` for execution on a CPU? As far as I know, most linear algebra operators are actually implemented by Eigen, but I'd like to know what Eigen functions specifically are being called.

I've tried tracing back from the high-level API, but this is difficult as there are a lot of steps between placing an operator on the graph, and the actual execution of the operator by the TF runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implementation is hidden behind some meta-template programming (not unusual for Eigen).

Each operation in TensorFlow is registered at some point. `Add` is registered [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/cwise_op_add_1.cc) and [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/cwise_op_add_2.cc).

```
REGISTER3(BinaryOp, GPU, "Add", functor::add, float, Eigen::half, double);
```

The actual implementation of Operations is based on [`OpKernel`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/754048a0453a04a761e112ae5d99c149eb9910dd/tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.h#L69). The `Add` operation is implemented in [`BinaryOp::Compute`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/70da85b727c960f62af141770827367f9c5c0117/tensorflow/core/kernels/cwise_ops_common.h#L91) The class hierarchy would be `BinaryOp : BinaryOpShared : OpKernel`

In the case of adding two scalars, the entire implementation is just:

```
functor::BinaryFunctor<Device, Functor, 1>().Right(
            eigen_device, out_flat, in0.template flat<Tin>(),
            in1.template scalar<Tin>(), error_ptr);
```

where `in0, in1` are the incoming Tensor-Scalars, `Device` is either GPU or CPU, and `Functor` is the operation itself. The other lines are just for performing the broadcasting.

Scroll down in this file and expanding the [`REGISTER3`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/70da85b727c960f62af141770827367f9c5c0117/tensorflow/core/kernels/cwise_ops_common.h#L576) macro explains how the arguments are passed from `REGISTER3` to `functor::BinaryFunctor<Device, Functor, ...>`.

You cannot expect to see some loops as Eigen use Expressions to do Lazy Evaluation and Aliasing. The Eigen-"Call" is here:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/7a0def60d45c1841a4e79a0ddf6aa9d50bf551ac/tensorflow/core/kernels/cwise_ops.h#L693-L696